# How do I change the link path when a button is clicked?

Tags: jquery

How do I change the link path when the button is clicked?

For example, how do I change the URL from http://www.google.com to http://stackoverflow.com in the following code?

```
<div id="path"><a href="http://www.google.com"></a></div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click" />


$("#btn").click(function(){});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
  $('#path a').attr("href", "http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

I believe there is a better way to set the href, but this will work

Comment: Now rather than fixing typo in my answer +1 to you :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$("#path a").attr("href", "http://stackoverflow.com");
```